# A question mark instead of reference number appears when \cite is in a separate file inlcuded in the main file by \include

Tags: bibtex, include

I am using the book style and each chapter is put in a separate file and included in the main file by `\include`. At the end of the main file, I put the following lines:

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{D:/paper/Bibtex/refguo}
```

But when I cite a reference in Chapter 1, for instance, which is in a separate file, a question mark [?] appears instead of the right reference number. But at the end of the PDF file produced, the references are correctly listed.

I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: Can you provide an MWE? It would make it easier for people to help you.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: Are you using `\includeonly`?

Comment: @Anke right community tools are at [meta.tex.sx](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/430/15717), use them prudently, a newbie may not follow MWE

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3):

Probably you just need another LaTeX run.

1. LaTeX writes a citation into the `.aux` files. In case of included files via `\include` it is the `.aux` file for the included file. If a citation `\cite{xyz}`  is added, then you should see `\citation{xyz}` in the right `.aux` file after the
   next LaTeX run.
2. Then bibtex should be run. It collects all `\citation` statements from the
   `.aux` files and writes the bibliography.
3. In the next LaTeX run after bibtex the bibliography is present with the
   new reference. But LaTeX does not know yet, which references the bibliography
   will contain. It records this in the `.aux` file with `\bibcite{xyz}{1}` (the second argument is the citation form).
   Thus you get still `[?]` for the new citation.
4. Another LaTeX run is needed, at the beginning it reads the `.aux` files with `\bibcite` and knows, how to cite `xyz` and you get `[1]` for `\cite{xyz}`, for example.

In summary, the following runs are needed after a citation is added:

- 1 × LaTeX
- 1 × BiBTeX
- **2** × LaTeX